# Pass arguments to nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code duplication that I'd like to factorize.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    reqOptions = {...};
    request(reqOptions, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error) {
            res.statusCode = response.statusCode;
            res.json(body)
        }
        else {
            res.statusCode = 503;
            res.json(body)
        }
    });
});
```

The logic in the `request` callback is always the same, and I try to find a way to get it out into a reusable function, like this :

```
function requestCallback(error, reponse, body) { 
    ....
}

app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    reqOptions = {...};
    request(reqOptions, requestCallback);
});
```

My problem is : how can I get access to `req` and `res` in the `requestCallback()` function ? Do I need to pass everything as arguments ?

Many thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind()`

```
function requestCallback(_req, _res, error, reponse, body) { 
    ....
}

request(reqOptions, requestCallback.bind(null, req, res));
```

Comment: @trincot Updated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can just simply pass req and res as arguments to requestCallback()